# Does my computer have a virus?

Tags: google-chrome, virus

Recently, I clicked on a link in another SE user profile (the link indicated it is personal blog/site). The link directed to some site full of porn ads. I did not clicked on anything beside the link and just closed the site.

However, when I reopened my chrome I noticed this little ad under recently viewed sites:
[image]

Frankly, I do not know whether it always was there or not. Nowadays many companies put ads everywhere so I filter them out.

Should I be worried? I run an norton antivirus scan of my computer, no threats where detected but I am not sure if there isnt any problem.

Any advice on what to do?

Comment: **[Fitbit](https://store.google.com/us/category/fitbit?pli=1&hl=en-US) is owned by Google.**  So what exactly is your worry?  Google advertises all it's products on the Start page within Chrome.

Comment: @Ramhound oh ok, so this is normal? I know this might sound stupid but somehow I never noticed it. I also live in NL and this did not used to be there. I worried its some sort of malware

Comment: Windows 10, go to Windows Defender security center and to a full scan, and then do an Offline Scan. Nothing found means you are OK.